# Selenium webdriver (facebook). Chrome browser is no loading secure(https) pages

Tags: php, facebook, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

Can't open secure pages with chrome browser.
All namespaces are included, everything works fine except https traffic.
Here is code which launches browser:

```
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability("profile.default_content_settings.cookies", 1);
$capabilities->setCapability("disable-save-password-bubble", true);
$capabilities->setCapability("--ignore-certificate-errors", true);
$capabilities->setCapability("chrome.switches", array("--ignore-certificate-errors", "--user-data-dir=/home/dev/.config/chromium/Default", "--no-sandbox"));
$capabilities->setCapability(WebDriverCapabilityType::ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
$capabilities->setCapability(WebDriverCapabilityType::WEB_STORAGE_ENABLED, true);
$web_driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities);
```

Does anyone know how to automate selemnium tests with chrome for https traffic?

Comment: Is your test environment pretected with user name and password (vhosts)? Are you running your tests against a local environment?

Comment: When I use firefox(geckodriver) everything is fine. https traffic works. There is another problem with firefox.

Comment: Is there some error given by the selenium console log? Could you please take a look to the selenium logs? Is the browser open and it remains in a blank page or it crashes? Please, give me some more information in order I can help you.

Comment: Chrome browser actually shows that page has loaded. But no content is displayed. And any further tests work without browser displaying content. Maybe page loads. No content is visible and webDriver fails to findElement which should be in DOM. If I skip test which uses https traffic then other tests run showing browsers content.

Comment: Only error I get in console is NoSuchElementException

Comment: Strange... It should be no problem with running tests against https content...  As you say you are using geckodriver, are you running tests in Selenium3 beta? Try to run it against 2.53.X with chrome. Only to discard some beta problem or something like this. You could also try to not specify none of the specific chromedriver ssl capabilities to try... But I think I can't help you any more on this. Sorry...

Comment: Actually https traffic works. But when I first run https and then http. Result is that http fails to display content. And vice versa. This bug is on chromedriver. Any screenshots are black pictures.